# How do I create a merge request for a project?

Tags: version-control, community-official-site

I'd like to create a merge request for a drupal.org project. I found a page on drupal.org titled [Issue forks & merge requests](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/gitlab-integration/issue-forks-merge-requests) which seems to address this but I'm not really getting anywhere. The page says:

> On an issue page, make sure the fork is created and you have access.
>
> 1. If the fork has not been created yet, click “Fork {project}”
> 2. If you do not have push access yet, click “Get push access”
> 3. If you see “✓ You have push access,” you’re all set!

The only place I could find a "Fork" button was on https://git.drupalcode.org/project/project_name/-/forks. But when I click on that I see just see a namespace with my name, and a greyed out "select" button, which, if I hover over it, displays "You have reached your project limit". But I think I'm in the wrong place anyway.

The instructions start with "...on the issue page" so I created an issue on drupal.org for the project, on the issue page there are no links that mention "fork" anywhere to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the ability to fork a project needs to be enabled by every project's maintainer manually first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in [Issue forks & merge requests](https://www.drupal.org/drupalorg/docs/gitlab-integration/issue-forks-merge-requests) drupal.org only implements (so far) issue forks and merge requests related to those issue forks. Issue forks are still in development and enabled only on those projects that opted-in, a list of which is available in [Opt-in core issues into the Drupal.org Issue Forks and Merge Requests Beta](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalorg/issues/3152637): The list doesn't include the projects maintained from the Drupal Association, for which issue forks have been directly enabled from a Drupal Association employee.
The plan is making them available on all projects on November 10, 2020.

When issue forks are enabled, an issue opened for that project contains a button as in the following screenshot, taken from [Show commit activity for issue fork branches without merge requests](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalorg/issues/3179462).

> [image: screenshot]

When an issue fork has been created, there will be a different button, as in the following screenshot.

> [image: screenshot]

I didn't watch at the code used on drupal.org, but I expect the code checks users have the *Git user* role on drupal.org, which is given to the users who accepts the Git access agreement, or a Git account on Drupal.org, before allowing them to create an issue fork or obtain push access on an issue fork.

> [image: screenshot]

Merge requests aren't tested on DrupalCI, until [Test merge requests made in GitLab with DrupalCI](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_issue_file_test/issues/3072048) is marked as fixed. That could happen before, or after, issue forks are enabled on every project.

As for today, December 24, 2020, issue forks and merge requests have been enabled on every project hosted on drupal.org. Merge requests are tested by the DrupalCI instance running for drupal.org.